# How to iterate through every potential XML subelement using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openxml

I have a large XML file of over 45K contacts and I need to iterate through their subelement transactions into a SQL table.  I've looked at several solutions to this, using value(), node(), etc..., but no examples appear to have an XML structure close to mine:

```
<Contacts>
    <Contact>
        <ContactID>1234</ContactID>
        <ContactName>’John Doe’</ContactName>
        <DOB>09031978</DOB>
        <Address>’123 Main Street’</Address>
            <Transactions>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>4490</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Recliner’</ProductName>
                <Cost>123.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042020
                </Transaction>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>5678</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Lamp’</ProductName>
                <Cost>45.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042020
                <Transaction>
            </Transactions>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <ContactID>4567</ContactID>
        <ContactName>’Jane Doe’</ContactName>
        <DOB>05191984</DOB>
        <Address>’567 Fake Street’</Address>
            <Transactions>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>4378</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Coffee Table’</ProductName>
                <Cost>225.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042018
                </Transaction>
            </Transactions>
    </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I need these data in a result like below:

| ContactID | TransactionID | ProductName | Cost | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4490 | Recliner | 123.00 | 4 July 2020 |
| 1234 | 5678 | Lamp | 45.00 | 4 July 2020 |
| 4567 | 4378 | Coffee Table | 225.00 | 4 July 2018 |

I've tried a query using the following script:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc  
-- Execute a SELECT stmt using OPENXML rowset provider.  
SELECT *  
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Contacts/Contact/Transactions/Transaction',2)  
WITH (ContactID     int             '../ContactID',  
      TransactionID  int            'TransactionID',  
      ProductName   nvarchar(50)    'ProductName',  
      Cost          float           'Cost',  
      PurchaseDate  date            'PurchaseDate')
```

But this will return either a null for ContactID; or return only one transaction for each ContactID.  But I need it to iterate and get as many transactions as exist for a contact.

Any insights would be most welcome!

Comment: The provided data is not valid XML format, e.g.: `<PurchaseDate>` are unclosed tags. Is this a copy-paste of a portion of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid [sp_xml_preparedocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-preparedocument-transact-sql) because it uses large amounts of memory that can't be used by SQL Server until you remember to free it up by invoking [sp_xml_removedocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-removedocument-transact-sql).

What you're asking for can be easily achieved using [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) with a cross apply, e.g. (after fixing your XML sample):

```sql
declare @doc xml = N'<Contacts>
    <Contact>
        <ContactID>1234</ContactID>
        <ContactName>’John Doe’</ContactName>
        <DOB>09031978</DOB>
        <Address>’123 Main Street’</Address>
            <Transactions>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>4490</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Recliner’</ProductName>
                <Cost>123.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042020</PurchaseDate>
                </Transaction>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>5678</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Lamp’</ProductName>
                <Cost>45.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042020</PurchaseDate>
                </Transaction>
            </Transactions>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <ContactID>4567</ContactID>
        <ContactName>’Jane Doe’</ContactName>
        <DOB>05191984</DOB>
        <Address>’567 Fake Street’</Address>
            <Transactions>
                <Transaction>
                <TransactionID>4378</TransactionID>
                <ProductName>’Coffee Table’</ProductName>
                <Cost>225.00</Cost>
                <PurchaseDate>07042018</PurchaseDate>
                </Transaction>
            </Transactions>
    </Contact>
</Contacts>';

select
  Cont.value('ContactID[1]', 'int') as ContactID
  ,Trans.value('TransactionID[1]', 'int') as TransactionID
  ,Trans.value('ProductName[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as ProductName
  ,Trans.value('Cost[1]', 'float') as Cost
  ,convert(date, concat(substring(purDate,1,2), '/', substring(purDate,3,2), '/', substring(purDate,5,4)), 101) as PurchaseDate
from @doc.nodes('//Contact') nodes1(Cont)
cross apply nodes1.Cont.nodes('Transactions/Transaction') nodes2(Trans)
outer apply (
  select purDate = Trans.value('PurchaseDate[1]', 'nvarchar(8)')
) temp;
```

Which yields:

| ContactID | TransactionID | ProductName | Cost | PurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 4490 | ’Recliner’ | 123 | 2020-07-04 |
| 1234 | 5678 | ’Lamp’ | 45 | 2020-07-04 |
| 4567 | 4378 | ’Coffee Table’ | 225 | 2018-07-04 |

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!  The CROSS APPLY had been giving me trouble, but that did the job!

Comment: `/Contacts/Contact` will probably be faster, as will using `/text()` for each of the `.values` Also use `DATEFROMPARTS` to construct dates